# Getting error when adding libraries for youtube video upload

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am uploading video from phone to YouTube. I used this tutorial to upload video
http://sharecoding.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/youtube-host-video-by-youtube-data-api/#comment-264.
But when i add libraries it gives me error
     Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define     Lcom/google/gdata/data/youtube/VideoEntry;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gdata/data/youtube/VideoEntry;

Comment: You have this class twice :/ Added the library twice maybe? in two different projects referencing each other maybe

Comment: i did Facebook SDK integration only. here is the snapshot of my project http://postimg.org/image/9ncpd7qwj/

Comment: Now I am using this example to upload video on YouTube https://github.com/sohnkh/YoutubeUploadAndroidSampleV3 but i am getting error com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: Need Permission please guide me

Answer (score 0):

To upload videos from Android, all you need is a [Java uploads.](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java)

[YouTube Direct Lite](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/ResumableUpload.java) project shows the best way to upload.

Comment: YouTube Direct lite i used as per that link but i want to integrate it in my app. If you see above link of code it gives library integration, with the help of them upload video to youtube.